# How to reconnect to database within try-catch block?

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a java app that performs continuous nonstop rapid inserts into a MySQL database using Spring JDBCTemplate.  After a few minutes, apparently something happens on the database that breaks the db connection, and I get an exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I am able to catch the SQLException in code, so at this point I would like to re-establish the database connection and exit the catch block and proceed.

What is a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:  here is the method where the exception is caught:

```
public int insertRecord(final String sql,final Object[] paramArray, KeyHolder keyHolder) {

        Integer retStatus = jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() { 

            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) { 
                    String[] keyColNames=new String[1];
                    PreparedStatement ps = null;
                    try {
                        ps=con.prepareStatement(sql,keyColNames); 
                        if(paramArray!=null){
                            int size=paramArray.length;
                            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                                ps.setObject(i+1, paramArray[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
                        logger.debug("caught SQLexception, now what should I do?");
                        con.reconnectToDatabase();  // this method doesnt exist but is what I need!
                    }

                    return ps; 
                } 
            }, keyHolder);  
        return retStatus;
    }
```

Comment: Can possibly use recursion to call the function again in the `catch` and pass the parameters in the last possible state somehow, but this probably isn't good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

If you are wishing to simply reconnect the database, you could create a class specifically for this, make a getConnection method for it, and then simply return the re-established connection.
e.g:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

private Connection connection;
public String driverURL = "[Your driver URL]";

    public Connection getConnection(String user, String password) {
    try {
        //SQLServerDriver or whichever you are using
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(driverURL, username, password);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

And then:

```
con = new ConnectionManager().getConnection(user, pass);
```

From there you can call the method again and retry the insert or go about it however you please.

Comment: I'm using a special method for the inserter that returns the primary key that I need.  I will paste the code indicating where the exception is caught, indicating how I'd like to process it if possible, since I have the Connection object but don't know how to restore that Connection which is now invalid.   Well, it's too long to insert the code here, I'll update the question with it

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I implemented something like this, but it turns out that when the connection dies, the mysql db is inaccessible from any client until I stop the tomcat container that the insert code is running in. Calling "datasource.getConnection()" re-establishes the connection if I manually turned off the service but doesnt fix it if it locks up after a minute of constant inserts.  After killing tomcat, I can access the DB from other clients like squirrel. Wondering if a change in my code will enable the db to accept inserts without locking up the database?

Comment: I changed my datasource from the Spring DriverManagerDataSource to the Apache dbcp2 BasicDataSource, which seems to have fixed the issue